# Wie finde ich das Nomen zu einem Artikel in einem langen Satz?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In dem Buch "Kryptowährung Bitcoin" habe ich folgenden Satz gelesen:

> Soziale Leistungen können dadurch wesentlich effizienter erbracht werden: dies ist die Zukunft der sozialen Gesellschaft, die **den** durch den Markt erwirtschafteten Wohlstand wirksam auf alle Schultern verteilt.

Zu wem gehört "den" hier in diesem Zusammenhang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Den* gehört dem Wohlstand. Andere Möglichkeiten gibt es auch nicht.

It is not unusual in the German that a descriptive clause is put between the article and the noun itself:

> das *an der Ecke stehende* Haus (das Haus, das an der Ecke steht).
>
> die *durch den Schnee bedeckten* Berge (die Berge, die durch den Schnee bedeckt sind)
>
> der *durch den Markt erwirtschaften* Wohlstand (der Wohlstand, der durch den Markt erwirtschaftet wurde).

Comment: warum wird  Wohlstand von den gespaltet @Eller

Comment: @user26646: it's *Klammern* everywhere in German. Items belonging to something else are *embraced* by parts of that other item.

Comment: @Janka danke Schön

Comment: @Eller, it's not only articles that may lead such a *Klammer*, but any separable part of an item: *dein neues(,) dort drüben auf dem Parkplatz stehendes rotes Auto*. Optional: comma.